# Configurable Product Display Issue From Backend

Tags: configurable-product, backend

Guys needs **help/suggestion** fixing issue for **configurable product** with **variations** products approx 20, We are facing error in back-end

```
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1755320320) (tried to allocate 268435464 bytes) in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 46
```

This seems to be known issue & also raised in [Github issue page](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/17992) but can't see any working solution

**Tried below solution** :

- Increase Memory limit: - Not worked
- Increase max_input_var: Not worked
- Code update as shown in Github issue fix : Not worked